# Send contact form to list of addresses based on selected option

Tags: email

I want to create a contact form with many fields. One of these fields will be 'County" and will be presented as a drop down menu. When a user selects a certain 'County', I want that email to be sent to a pre-defined list of email addresses set for that county only.

Eg,

```
<select>
<option value="cumbria">Cumbria</option>
<option value="lancashire">Lancashire</option>
<option value="yorkshire">Yorkshire</option>
</select>
```

Each option value will have its own list of email address so when a user selects one, only the addresses in that list for that option will receive the form.

I hope this all makes sense.